# Passed props property (prop.property) becomes undefined ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Currently I am trying to use `localStorage` as a communication tool for the project. Basically my idea is, UI elements (buttons, checkboxes, etc.) edit a JSON file's deep copy (Also a variable `LayersData` then give it to `useEffect`'s dependency to re-render) then push it to localStorage (in `NestedMenu` comp), then read in another file (in `MapComponentv2`) and in that instant a change is occurred so `useEffect` dependency should trigger a re-render with new data. At the moment I try to triger visibility of a map layer from checkbox toggle in its own state. (There should be no need to restart the app.)

After I added `LayersData` logic, it does not render any map layers any more, never. Before this execution try of this logic it can bring the layers with toggle but page needed to be refreshed.

`LayersData` can be read in `App.jsx` but can not be read in any of the component files, besides no layers are loading anymore no matter the refresh.

Main Issue: (Stored and get from to `localStorage` at App file so problem is not from there I believe) After Passed as a prop to children, properties of JSON file couldn't read.

Errors:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
    at sublayerVisibility (MapComponentv2.jsx:19:42)
    at MapComponentv2.jsx:110:21
// In sublayerVisibility I took a bool of true or false to edit sublayers visibility bot after
```

Think that both error comes from same reason since before I execute this idea there weren't any of them

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'structuredClone' on 'Window': (newData) => {
    setLayersData(newData);
    localStorage.setItem("fakelayers", JSON.stringify(newData));
   ...<omitted>... } could not be cloned.
    at handleLayerVisibility (http://localhost:5173/src/components/NestedMenu.jsx:42:24)
    at onChange (http://localhost:5173/src/components/NestedMenu.jsx:81:9)
    at handleInputChange (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@mui_material.js?v=677c4bfd:7490:7)
...
```

Here comes the code files:

**App.jsx**

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState , useEffect } from 'react';
import MiniDrawer from './components/IconedDrawer.jsx'
import NestedMenu from './components/NestedMenu.jsx'
import MapComponent from './components/not used/MapComponent.jsx';
import MapComponentv2 from './components/MapComponentv2.jsx';
import importedData from './components/data/fakelayers.json';
const jsonlayers = JSON.stringify(importedData);
localStorage.setItem('fakelayers', jsonlayers);



function App() {
    const [LayersData, setLayersData] = useState((JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fakelayers'))));
    /* console.log(LayersData.layers.find(e=>e.layer === "Base Maps, Plans")); */
    const updateLayersData = (newData) => {
    setLayersData(newData);
    localStorage.setItem('fakelayers', JSON.stringify(newData));
    console.log("LayersData updated!");
  };
    console.log(LayersData.layers);
    useEffect(() => {
    const handleLocalStorageChange = (e) => {
      if (e.key === 'fakelayers') {
        const newLayersData = JSON.parse(e.newValue);
        setLayersData(newLayersData);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('storage', handleLocalStorageChange);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('storage', handleLocalStorageChange);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
  <>
    <MapComponentv2 LayersData = {LayersData}/>
    <MiniDrawer LayersData= {LayersData} updateLayersData = {updateLayersData}/>
  </>
  )
}


export default App
```

---

**MapComponentv2.jsx**

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Map from '@arcgis/core/Map.js';
import SceneView from '@arcgis/core/views/SceneView.js';
import TileLayer from '@arcgis/core/layers/TileLayer.js';
import esriConfig from "@arcgis/core/config.js";
import IntegratedMeshLayer from '@arcgis/core/layers/IntegratedMeshLayer.js';
import SceneLayer from '@arcgis/core/layers/SceneLayer.js';
import ElevationLayer from '@arcgis/core/layers/ElevationLayer.js';
import FeatureLayer from '@arcgis/core/layers/FeatureLayer.js';
import GroupLayer from '@arcgis/core/layers/GroupLayer.js';
import BaseMap from '@arcgis/core/BaseMap.js';
import LayerList from "@arcgis/core/widgets/LayerList.js";


 function sublayerVisibility(layername, sublayername, jsonobject){
  var visibility = null;

  const sublayerData = jsonobject.layers.find(e => e.layer === layername);
        if (sublayerData) {
        visibility = sublayerData.sublayers[sublayername];}
        else{
        visibility = false;
        }
        return visibility;
} 

esriConfig.apiKey = "MYAPIKEY";

function MapComponentv2(LayersData) {
  console.log(LayersData);
  const sceneViewRef = useRef(null);
  const [view, setView] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initialMap = new Map({
      basemap: "hybrid",
      listMode: 'hide'
    });

    const sceneView = new SceneView({
      container: sceneViewRef.current,
      map: initialMap,
      camera: {
        tilt: 45,
        heading: 0,
        position: {
          latitude: 21.47840,
          longitude: 39.18526,
          z: 650,
        }
      },
      environment: {
        atmosphere: {
          quality: "high"
        },
        lighting: {
          date: new Date(),
          directShadowsEnabled: true
        }
      },
    });

    setView(sceneView);

    return () => {
      sceneView.container = null;
      sceneView.destroy();
    };   
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (view ) {
      view.when(() => {
        // View is fully loaded here
        // Add your 3D layers or other configurations
        // Did not provide layers since they are confidential, if needed can provide default layers
        // sceneLayer is a test layer for those who wants to try

       const sceneLayer = new SceneLayer({
          portalItem: {
            id: "2e0761b9a4274b8db52c4bf34356911e"
          },
          popupEnabled: false
        });
        
        
        if (view.map) {
          view.map.addMany(sceneLayer);
        }
       


        
      });
    }
  }, [view, LayersData]);

  const containerStyle = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  };

  return (
  <div>
    {/* <div id="layerListContainer" ref={layerListRef} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '10px', right: '10px', zIndex: 1000 }}></div> */}
    <div id="map" ref={sceneViewRef} style={containerStyle}></div>
    
  </div>
    
  );
}

export default MapComponentv2;
```

---

**NestedMenu.jsx**

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import * as React from 'react';
import {Checkbox, ThemeProvider} from '@mui/material'
import {List} from '@mui/material';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import Collapse from '@mui/material/Collapse';
import ExpandLess from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandLess';
import ExpandMore from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ReactIcon from './assets/react.svg';
/* import { useLayerData } from './MapComponentv2'; */




export default function NestedMenu({children, name, LayersData, updateLayersData }) {

        /* const {fakelayersData, updateFakelayersData} = useFakelayers(); */
        
        const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
        const checkboxlist=[];
        const handleClick = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
        
    }
        function handleLayerVisibility(name,element, jsonfile) {
            
            var deepcopyJSON = structuredClone(jsonfile);
            const sublayerData = jsonfile.layers.find(layer => layer.layer === name);
            
            /* console.log(name,element, sublayerData); */
            deepcopyJSON.layers.find(layer=> layer.layer === name).sublayers[element] = !deepcopyJSON.layers.find(layer=> layer.layer === name).sublayers[element];
                
            /* console.log(deepcopyJSON); */
            localStorage.setItem('fakelayers', JSON.stringify(deepcopyJSON));
            console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fakelayers')));

            updateLayersData(deepcopyJSON);
            
            
            
        }
        
    return (
        <div>
            <ListItemButton onClick={()=> { handleClick();}}>
                {/* <ListItemIcon
                >
                <img src={ReactIcon}/>
                </ListItemIcon> */}
                <ListItemText primary={name} disableTypography sx={{fontSize:'13px'}}/>
                {open ? (
                <ExpandLess />
                ) : (
                <ExpandMore />
                )}
            </ListItemButton>
            <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                <List component="div" disablePadding >
                    {children.map((element,index) =>(
                    <ListItem key={element} disablePadding sx={{ display: 'block' }} >
                        <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
                        <Checkbox 
                        defaultChecked= {JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fakelayers')).layers.find(e => e.layer === name).sublayers[element]} 
                        onChange={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); handleLayerVisibility(name, element, LayersData); }}>
                        </Checkbox>
                            <ListItemText primary={element} disableTypography sx={{fontSize:'12px'}}/>
                        </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                    ))}
                </List>
            </Collapse>
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

fakelayers.json

```
{
    
    "layers":[
    {
        "layer": "Base Maps, Plans",
        "sublayers": {"sceneLayer":true,"Orthophoto":false,"me":false,"th":false,"ing":false},
        "id":"0"
    },
    
    {   "layer": "Nature, Environment",
        "sublayers": {"so":false,"me":false,"th":false,"ing":false},
        "id":"1"
    },
    
    {
        "layer": "3D Data, Applications",
        "sublayers": {"3D City Mesh":true,"me":false,"th":false,"ing":false},
        "id":"2"
    },
    {
        "layer": "Special Applications",
        "sublayers": {"way":false, "aaaaaaa":false},
        "id":"3"
    }
    
]
    
}
```